# Where do I get basic mechanical components?

Tags: mechanisms

I'm looking for a few basic devices such as converting translational to rotational motion, 20:1 gearbox, etc. Found nothing at Home Depot. Could you suggest where does one buys/orders such components?

Comment: Try macmasters-carr

Comment: Try part suppliers for robotics hobbyists.

Comment: This question would have potential as a community wiki where the answer is a collection of vendors. I've listed a few in my answer, but there are many more.

Comment: This looks like a [resource-hunting question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/10/1832). Such questions are prone to becoming out-dated, and are therefore considered off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are my go to sources:

- [Pic Design](https://www.pic-design.com) (Good for gears, screws and other components)
- [Stock Drive](https://www.sdp-si.com) (Similar to Pic Design)
- [WM Berg](https://www.wmberg.com) (Good collection of parts. Particularly good for chain and belt drives and alternatives)
- [McMaster-Carr](https://www.mcmaster.com) (Broad range of products)
- [Century Spring](https://www.centuryspring.com/) (Awesome for springs)

Answer (score 1):

If you are a company you should definitely go look on Misumi but they don’t sell to private.
Otherwise you could google for what you need and in most cases you will find some website selling it. I bought bearings, gearboxes and motors without issues of any kind.

Comment: Alas, I'm not a company. :-(